# Django uploading a file from a form fails to validate

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a media library for my personal website. I can upload files in the django admin just fine through a FileField but I want to be able to do in my media library page instead. When I try to validate the form I get from the media library page form.is_valid() fails and returns Not Found: /media/

My MEDIA_URL is media/

```
# views.py
class MediaView(UpdateView):
    form_class = FileForm
    model = File
    template_name = 'myapp/media.html'

    def get(self, request):
        if (request.user.is_superuser):

            form = self.form_class(None)
            files = File.objects.all()

            return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'files': files})
        else:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

    def post(self, request):

        if (not request.user.is_superuser):
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if (form.is_valid()):
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            file = form.cleaned_data['file']

            media = form.save(commit=False)

            if (not name):
               media.name = name
            media.file = file

            media = form.save()

            return redirect('/media')
        else:
            return HttpResponseNotFound()

    # models.py
    class File(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
        file = models.FileField()
        date_uploaded = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

        def __str__(self):
        if (not self.name):
            return str(self.file)
        else:
            return self.name

    # (template) media.py
    <div class="flex-container">
<div class="flex-column content">
    <h1>Media</h1>
    <form class="upload-form" role="form" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <span class="upload-file-cover">Choose File:</span>
        <button class="button" type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="media-uploads">
        {% for file in files %}
            <li>
                <p class="clipboard-text">/{{ file.file.url }}</p>
                <a class="copy-to-clipboard">
                    {{ file|filetypeicon }}
                    <div class="tooltip">Copy to clipboard</div>
                </a>
                <a href="/{{ file.file.url }}" target="_blank">{{ file }}</a>
                <a href="/delete/media/{{ file.id }}" class="delete">Delete</a>
            </li>
        {% empty %}
            Nothing here.
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% include "personal/includes/sidebar-latest.html" %}
{% include "personal/includes/sidebar-profile.html" %}
```

```
# forms.py
from personal.models import File
from django import forms

class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ['name', 'file']
```

Comment: I'm sure `self.form_class` in POST method expecting another argument called `request.FILES` so uploaded files will process by Django form.

Comment: Ah indeed so, was totally was unaware I needed that argument. Got it from not in the django docs. Thanks <3

or perhaps not, am I missing anything else a little less obvious?

Comment: I wrote an answer for the same

Comment: post your urls.py and what about MEDIA_ROOT? have you declared it?

Comment: My MEDIA_ROOT is the same as my MEDIA_URL media/ in this case a relative path into my project folder. I am serving the files with django for debug right now (if settings.DEBUG is True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When processing User uploaded file Django expecting another argument called request.FILES along with request.POST.

### POST method

```
form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: I have applied this now and looked over the docs to see if I had anything else wrong. Thanks for the step in the right direction but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Okay. If form is not valid then can you  `print(form.errors)` ?

Comment: I get a field is required error "<ul class="errorlist"><li>file<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>" which is strange now that I'm passing the form all the parameters

Comment: Too long for comments, can we move this to live chat?

Comment: I think you need 20 rep for live chat ?

Comment: I know, I can't start one but I have been able to be invited into one before.

Comment: Well you forgot to include `enctype=multipart/form-data`